# Posting binary file and name in the same request in AngularJS and Flask

Tags: python, angularjs, http, flask, blob

I am trying to upload (post) a file and its filename in the same request in angular and then receive it in Flask and write to disc. The file is read from local disc using:

```
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(importData.ruleFile.files[0]);
```

The http request is:

```
$http({
    url: baseUrlService.baseURL + 'importtifile',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
    data: {
        filename: importData.ruleFileName,
//        filedata: new DataView(reader.result)
//        filedata: reader.result
        filedata: new Uint8Array(reader.result)
    },

    transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('filename', data.filename);
        formData.append('filedata', data.filedata);
        return formData;
    }

}).then(
...
```

And the flask part is:

```
@api.route('/importfile', methods=['POST'])
def import_file():
    file_name = request.form['filename']
    file_data = request.form['filedata']

    f = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    f.write(file_data)
    f.close()
```

The issue is:

When I send file from angular as **new DataView(reader.result)** the file that the server writes contains only one string:

> [object DataView]

If I send it as new **Uint8Array(reader.result)** the file that the server writes contains just the string:

> [object Uint8Array]

How can I get the actual data transferred?

I tried to read file readAsBinaryString, but in that case the file that is written on the server side is about twice as big as original.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I figured out all I need to transfer is Blob:

angularJS:

```
        // Send file as Blob along with its filename
        $http({
            url: baseUrlService.baseURL + 'importtifile',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
            data: { filedata: fileBlob },

            uploadEventHandlers: {
                progress: function(e) {
                    importData.fileUploadProgress = e;

                    console.log(importData.fileUploadProgress);
                }
            },

            transformRequest: function (data, headersGetter) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('fileblob', data.filedata);
                return formData;
            }

        }).then(
            ...
```

In the flask part one can extract both file blob and name:

```
@api.route('/importfile', methods=['POST'])
def import_file():
    file_obj = request.files['fileblob']
```

and **file_obj.filename** will contain the file name.